# Building Linked List in Rust

Tags: rust, linked-list, lifetime

I am trying to make a linked list implementation in rust to get used to the language. I am very new and concept of lifetimes is still pretty complicated so I came across the problem.

```rust
impl<'l> LinkedList<'l> {
    pub fn new() -> LinkedList<'l> {
        LinkedList {
            _head: None,
            _tail: None,
            _size: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn addToFront(&mut self,value: isize){
        let nodeToAdd = Node {
            data: value,
            _prev: None,
            _next: None
        };

        self._head = Some(&nodeToAdd); 
    }
}
```

the last line gives me an error. It says "`nodeToAdd` does not live long enough." I thought that changing it to `Some(&'l nodeToAdd)` could help but this is not valid code. I appreciate if you can suggest to fix this.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) which is specifically about learning Rust with linked lists.

Comment: `addToFront` cannot work as written because it creates a local variable, and then assigns a reference to that local variable to the linked list. Since the local will be deallocated the moment `addToFront` returns, the compiler tells you that the "value doesn't live long enough". You want the linked list to own the values in head and tail, so you need to use a _box_ (a smart pointer) rather than a reference for those fields. See the tutorial for details.

Comment: @user4815162342 thank you. I haven’t learned about *box* yet. I will check out the tutorial.